# How to know total value of buying and selling of a wallet via web3

Tags: web3js, wallets, ethereumjs, exchanges, transfer

I want to know how much a wallet has bought and sold the assets. I need to know it in dollars. For example, 500$ of assets bought and sold by a wallet

Something like this is possible in web3?

Answer (score 1):

You basically have 2 options.

The first is to set up a node and **crawl the whole blockchain** for token transfers.

The second is to **use a third-party service** such as Alchemy, which has already crawled the blockchain and returns the list of all the holdings. Read more about it [here](https://docs.alchemy.com/docs/how-to-get-all-tokens-owned-by-an-address).

Answer (score 0):

You can also track the dex where they brought and sold the tokens for events involving that specific address.